# How to customize column mappings with Spark Cassandra Connector in Java?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I wanted to change a column mapping to be append.  Is there a better way to customize the column mappings with Spark Cassandra Connector in Java than the following?

```
 ColumnName song_id = new ColumnName("song_id", Option.empty());
 CollectionColumnName key_codes = new ColumnName("key_codes", Option.empty()).append();
 List<ColumnRef> collectionColumnNames = Arrays.asList(song_id, key_codes);
 scala.collection.Seq<ColumnRef> columnRefSeq = JavaApiHelper.toScalaSeq(collectionColumnNames);

 javaFunctions(songStream)
                .writerBuilder("demo", "song", mapToRow(PianoSong.class))
                .withColumnSelector(new SomeColumns(columnRefSeq))
                .saveToCassandra();
```

This is taken from [this Spark Streaming code](https://github.com/retroryan/piano-java/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/piano/SparkStreaming.java) sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your column ref's using the 
[CollectionColumnName](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/16a6154884a02255d514f105f170b52ddbee96f4/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/ColumnRef.scala#L52)

Which has a constructor

```
case class CollectionColumnName(
    columnName: String,
    alias: Option[String] = None,
    collectionBehavior: CollectionBehavior = CollectionOverwrite) extends ColumnRef
```

You can rename by setting `alias` and you can change the insert behavior with `collectionBehavior` which takes the following classes.

[Api Link](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/16a6154884a02255d514f105f170b52ddbee96f4/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/ColumnRef.scala#L27-L32)

```
/** Insert behaviors for Collections. */
sealed trait CollectionBehavior
case object CollectionOverwrite extends CollectionBehavior
case object CollectionAppend extends CollectionBehavior
case object CollectionPrepend extends CollectionBehavior
case object CollectionRemove extends CollectionBehavior
```

Which means you can just do

```
CollectionColumnName appendColumn = 
  new CollectionColumnName("ColumnName", Option.empty(), CollectionPrepend$.MODULE$);
```

Which looks a bit more Java-y and is a bit more explicit. Did you have any other goals for this code?